# How to use messenger ipc protocol over SPP Bluetooth connection within Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, ipc, specifications, android-bluetooth

How do you use Android Messengers (IPC) when communicating over Bluetooth?

Is there some kind of specification for Android IPC using Messengers over a SPP Bluetooth connection between two smartphones running the same App?

I am not so fond of reinventing the wheel myself and drawing conclusions afterwards about my own design mistakes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you use Android Messengers (IPC) when communicating over Bluetooth?

You don't.

> Is there some kind of specification for Android IPC using Messengers over a SPP Bluetooth connection between two smartphones running the same App?

No, sorry. `Messenger` is specifically designed, along with the rest of the Binder framework, for communications within a device, not between devices.

Comment: Great! Now I can stop my search on getting that working :)  How on earth am I going to communicate between two smartphones using Bluetooth. Design my own byte-wise communication protocol for that?